# Can't promisify callback based function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-promisify

I want to use the library [aztro-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aztro-js) where a typical call in their docs looks like this:

```
const aztroJs = require("aztro-js");

//Get all horoscope i.e. today's, yesterday's and tomorrow's horoscope
aztroJs.getAllHoroscope(sign, function(res) {
   console.log(res);
});
```

For several reasons, I would like to use it using async/await style and leverage try/catch. So I tried promisify like this:

```
const aztroJs = require("aztro-js");
const {promisify} = require('util');
const getAllHoroscopeAsync = promisify(aztroJs.getAllHoroscope);

async function handle() {
  let result, sign = 'libra';
  try {
    result = await getAllHoroscopeAsync(sign);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("Result: " + result);
}
```

However, when I log result it comes as undefined. I know the call worked since the library is automatically logging a response via console.log and I see a proper response in the logs.

How can I "await" on this call? (even by other means if this one is not "promisifyable")

Comment: `promisify` expects a callback where the first argument is an/the error.

Comment: a) make sure to get the `this` context of the method right b) make sure that the method complies with the nodeback convention.

Comment: `const getAllHoroscopeAsync = promisify((sign, cb) => { aztroJs.getAllHoroscope(sign, res => { cb(null, res); }); });` should work.

Comment: your code seems to be ok..How are you calling your handle method??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`util.promisify()` expects the callback function to accept two arguments, the first is an error that must be `null` when there is no error and non-null when there is an error and the second is the value (if no error).  It will only properly promisify a function if the callback follows that specific rule.

To work around that, you will have to manually promisify your function.

```
// manually promisify
aztroJs.getAllHoroscopePromise = function(sign) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        aztroJs.getAllHoroscope(sign, function(data) {
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
};

// usage
aztroJs.getAllHoroscopePromise(sign).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Note, it's unusual for an asynchronous function that returns data not to have a means of returning errors so the `aztroJs.getAllHoroscope()` interface seems a little suspect in that regard.

In fact, if you look at the [code for this function](https://github.com/srijitcoder/aztro-js/blob/master/aztro-js/aztro.js), you can see that it is making a network request using the `request()` library and then trying to `throw` in the async callback when errors.  That's a completely flawed design since you (as the caller) can't catch exceptions thrown asynchronously.  So, this package has no reasonable way of communicating back errors.  It is designed poorly.

Answer (score 2):

Try custom promisified function

```
aztroJs.getAllHoroscope[util.promisify.custom] = (sign) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    aztroJs.getAllHoroscope(sign, resolve);
  });
};

const getAllHoroscopeAsync = util.promisify(aztroJs.getAllHoroscope);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your getAllHoroscopeAsync to a promise function

Example:

```
const getAllHoroscopeAsync = (sign) => 
    new Promise(resolve => 
            aztroJs.getAllHoroscope(sign, (res) => resolve(res)));
```